# No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_apps" when I try to authenticate with omniauth-google-oauth2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, oauth-2.0, google-openid

I have implemented twitter and facebook authentication with omniauth gem, but when i try to authenticate with openID or google I get: No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_apps" or No route matches [GET] "/auth/open_id" errors

My omniauth.rb file is:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :openid, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'openid'
provider :openid, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
```

And my routes.rb is that:

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'authentications#create'
```

And my Gemfile is this:

```
#for user authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

I have to put anything else in my code to run OpenID and google authentication? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your calls are erroneous. You should call :

```
/auth/google
```

Answer (score 0):

```
provider :openid, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp')
```

use this code instead, and link /auth/google